# Crafting a dynamic base url

Tags: php, replace

I have a constant building a dynamic base_url:

```
define('BASE_URL', "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

The current base_url

> http://training:8888/php/PHP6:MySQL%205/16/user_registration/htdocs/test.php/index.php

I've used:

```
echo(BASE_URL . '/index.php' . "<br />"); // Define the URL:

echo str_ireplace('htdocs/','', BASE_URL ); //Not the desired result
```

I found these forum post with an almost identical query as mine:[Post One](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=165220) and [Post 2](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/php-how-to-get-main-or-base-url/).

If you could add insight to there solutions it would be appreciated. Your patience is appreciated.

Comment: Have you even taken the time to look into any one of the "vast number of native PHP functions", like [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)?

Comment: str_ireplace() was mentioned in the question. I simply wanted an assist in refining my usage, and ensure I was indeed using it correctly.(echo str_ireplace('htdocs/','', BASE_URL ); Sorry to offend.

Comment: Nobody's offended. In your original question, you never made mention of what you had tried or that you needed help with "refining your usage". Your question can be summarized as, "Here's what I need to do. Here's how to do it. Now _you_ do it for me." I don't want to discourage you from using this forum, but I _do_ want to learn how to post better questions. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You **are** using it correctly: http://ideone.com/b7Mo8

```
$url = 'http://training:8888/php/PHP6:MySQL%205/16/user_registration/htdocs/index.php';
echo str_ireplace('htdocs/','', $url);
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideone site. Very helpful. I'll edit the question in hopes of clarification, my intention was lost in my frustration, not attempting to have someone "do my homework" :)